# Change the info in the second viewcontroller according to which row is selected in the first viewcontrollerios

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok first of all I have to say that I am a bit of a noob on the iOS field.
That said I will explain my problem further.

I am making an app in which the user gets a list of animals. When the user picks an animal from the list --> the second viewcontroller opens and the imageview there must be set to the selected animal + there is a description of the animal.

With this part of code in my ViewDidLoad of viewController2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Animal"];   //here the title has to be set to the animal but I will try this later

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UIImage * cowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cow.png"];
    UIImage * horseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"horse.png"];

    ViewController1 *viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];

    characterNumber = viewController1.pickedRow;

    //set the uiimageview based on characternumber
    switch (characterNumber) {
        case 0:
            foto.image = pukkelpopImage;
            detailInfo.text = @"blabla";
            [self.navigationItem setTitle:characterName];
            break;
        case 1:
            foto.image = cactusImage;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

In my ViewController 1.m I have this method for when an item gets selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    ViewController2 *ViewController22 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:ViewController22 animated:YES];

    pickedRow = indexPath.row;   //As you can see here I try to get which row was tapped


}
```

Where could the issue be? 
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating a new instance of viewController1 in viewController2, which is not related at all to the viewController1 instance pushing viewController2.

Try to declare a NSInteger property in viewController2 to store the picked row and set the value of viewController2 instance before you push it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

In ViewController2.h declare the property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger pickedRow;
```

In ViewController1.m didSelectRowAtIndexPath, set the property after you initialize the viewController2 instance, before you push it:

```
viewController2.pickedRow = indexPath.row;
```

No need to initialize the viewController1 in ViewController2.m:

```
// ViewController1 *viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
```

The variable characterNumber can be replaced with self.pickedRow.

Comment: Ok I don't understand what you are saying.
So in my ViewController2 I declare @property NSInteger *pickedRoww; and synthesize, what do I have to in ViewController 1 then?

Comment: You my friend, are the best :D
Thank you so much! It works, and I understand it :D